# Link to a specific tab view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I Have a tab bar controller designed like [this one](http://www.techotopia.com/images/1/1a/Xcode_5_ios_7_tab_bar_storyboard.png). I just added a "splash" screen with some links to those tab view controllers and i need to make a link from the splash page directly to each of the view controllers.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedIndex property of UITabbarController to activate the tab you want: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW2

```
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex
```